# Hide a response field in OpenApi / Swagger depending on the endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

The application contains two GET REST endpoints `/story` and `/review`. Both use the same dto `Article`:

```
public class Article {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private int numOfWords;
}
```

How can the dto `Article` be adjusted so that only the Swagger schema to `/story` includes the field `id` but not the Swagger schema to `/review`?

The response part of the Swagger documentation looks like this for both endpoints:

[image]

But it should look like above for `/story`
and like below for `/review`:
[image]

With the `@JsonIgnore` annotation over `private int id`, the field `id` does not appear in the Swagger schema, but it does not appear for both endpoints.

Comment: were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this annotation from `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter`

```
@Parameter(hidden = true) int id
```

It'll hide the id field.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, but then it's gone in both Swagger schemas.